# using autocomplete how to filter object on multiple attributes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am developing Angular 6 app, I want to iterate over this object. I am new to rxjs, I don't know how to filter object based on multiple attributes, though I tried my best to work something.

When I type in name or type it must auto complete and filter the object

This is what I have tried but this is not working

```
 **template.html**

     <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
           <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value] ="option">
               {{option.name}}
             </mat-option>
           </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field> 

**typescript.ts**

//object 

  objectOptions = [
  { name:'Angular', type:"xyz"  },
  { name:'Angular Material',type:"abc" },
  { name:'React', type:"mnq" },
  { name: 'vue', type:"sds" }
  ];

ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredOptions = this.customerFilterControl.valueChanges.pipe(                    
     startWith(''),
     map(value => this.filterx(value))
   );
 }  

 filterx(value:string):string[] {
     const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
     return this.objectOptions.map(function(x){if(x.name ||x.type) return x.name; //error detailed 
     below}).filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

error:If I return x map attribute complains as it returns only string[]

Comment: Your template uses `option.name`, where option is one of the elements of the array emitted by filteredOptions. So filteredOptions shouldn't be an Observable<string[]>, because arrays don't have any name. It should be an Observable<{name: string;}>. So your filterx function shouldn't return a string[]. What do you want filterx to do? Return all the options whose name or type contains the entered value? Something else?

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, you are correct, In template I want to display name and type like this option.name (option.type). And the filterx must return the entire object that either name or type

Comment: So you shouldn't call .map() on objectOptions. You should call .filter(), in order... to filter the options.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to rxjs   should filterx     return this.objectOptions.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));

Comment: This has nothing to do with RxJS. You have an array of options, and you want to filter this array. option.toLowerCase() can't be correct, since option is not a string, and thus doesn't have a toLowerCase() method. You want to check option.name.toLowerCase() includes the value, or option.type.toLowerCase() includes the value.

Comment: thats perfect :),its working now

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, however, for mat-option directive I have [value] attribute in this attr. I want to display option.type and option.name togather. I have added new question for this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992381/how-to-display-multiple-object-value-values-mat-option-or-bind-muliple-values-to

Comment: The value property is not what is displayed by the option. It's its value. What is displayed is what you have inside the mat-option element: `{{option.name}}`.

Comment: Yes I understand that once a value is chosen from drop down, I want this value to be displayed in the input box, so I have to bind [value] ="option.name + '('+ option.type + ')'"

Comment: No. Instead, you should use this: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @JB Nizet

```
**template.html**

     <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
           <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value] ="option">
               {{option.name}} {{option.type}}
             </mat-option>
           </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field> 

**typescript.ts**

//object 

  objectOptions = [
  { name:'Angular', type:"xyz"  },
  { name:'Angular Material',type:"abc" },
  { name:'React', type:"mnq" },
  { name: 'vue', type:"sds" }
  ];

ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredOptions = this.customerFilterControl.valueChanges.pipe(                    
     startWith(''),
     map(value => this.filterx(value))
   );
 }  

 filterx(value:string):string[] {
     const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
     return this.objectOptions.filter(function(option) {
       if(option.type.includes(filterValue) || option.name.includes(filterValue)) {
       return option;
     }
    });
```