# How to display multiple object value values mat-option or bind muliple values to [value] attribute of mat-option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In ref to question [using autocomplete how to filter object on multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990788/using-autocomplete-how-to-filter-object-on-multiple-attributes?noredirect=1#comment104233170_58990788), I have filtered object based on name and type. In the value attribute of mat-option I want to display objects name and type attribute togather, how to do this?

I tried [value] ="option.name (option.type)" I see errors

Comment: can you update the code you tried and errors you are getting? Try creating a demo.

Comment: value can be only one, if you need to display text then `{{ option.name (option.type) }}` will do the trick!

Comment: `value = "{{ option?.name +  ' (' + option?.type + ')' }}"`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it should be an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as a expression :

```
[value]="option?.name + ' ('+ option?.type + ')'"
```

OR

```
value = "{{ option?.name + ' (' + option?.type + ')' }}"
```

Comment: @karansys please try the same

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to modify original object itself *(which keeps html markup clean)* In terms of change or any other logic this will be helpful:

```
constructor() {
  this.objectOptions.forEach(obj => {
    obj.type = obj.name + '(' + obj.type + ')';
  });
}
```

It can be done with:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of objectOptions" [value]="option.type">
      {{option.name }}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, I want [value] attr to have name and type